# qt creator and VTK installation

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, vtk

im need to install qt creator and VTK to my windows7 x64 computer. i have downoaded and installed Qt creator and qt libraries from here ; http://qt-project.org/downloads Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 525 MB) .(yes i have installled vs2010 and vs2012 on my computer )

i wlll try to draw 3D objects using c++ with OOP . .But i don't know how to install VTK. i seached for it bu i couldn't find something good.Besides im new on using this tools and i don't know what to do .

if you help i appreciate

thanks ..

Comment: Why not use something like cmake?

Comment: For development on windows its really best in a lot of cases to not install VTK. But to build it using the compiler you will be using for your applications and always use CMake to generate your applications. Also if you do not absolutely need shared libraries I suggest turning these off when configuring vtk with cmake. I do this in all of my systems for years since I do not need shared libs so no need to write a cmake script to copy my vtk dlls to my application's binary folder for each configuration.

Comment: With that said I believe only the git version of vtk is compatible with Qt-5.X.

Comment: thanks for your reply i found a setup.exe and it solved my problem...